# Script doesn't move player to a part

Tags: lua, roblox

I was trying to make player teleport to certain object on the map but it just can't!

I don't know what to try

```
local items = {"Coal Chunk Tool", "Diamon Tool", "Iron Ingot Tool", 
"RokakakaFruit Tool", "Gold Ingot Tool"}
for _, v in pairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
    for _, d in pairs(items) do
        if v.Name == d then
            wait(1)
            game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:MoveTo(v.Position)
            print("tped")
        end
    end
end
```

my player just doesn't move

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the rest of your code, the MoveTo function will only attempt to make your player walk over there. What you want to do is change the CFrame of the player's character.

```
game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.Head.CFrame = CFrame.new(v.Position)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you should note when using the `:MoveTo()` method (in case the other person confused you):

- `:MoveTo()` called on a *Humanoid* will cause the player's character to walk towards its given destination
- `:MoveTo()` called on a *Model* will teleport the player's character

To teleport their character then, you will have to call this method on their character model. Additionally, there's no need to nest the second `for` loop inside the first. Just check the table for the given value.

```
local items = {"Coal Chunk Tool", "Diamon Tool", "Iron Ingot Tool", "RokakakaFruit Tool", "Gold Ingot Tool"}

for _, v in pairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
    if items[v.Name] then
        wait(1)
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character:MoveTo(v.Position)
        print("tped")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CFrame to move the player, we will need to use the HumanoidRootPart, so it moves the rest of the body!

See if this script makes a difference;

`local items = {"Coal Chunk Tool", "Diamon Tool", "Iron Ingot Tool", 
"RokakakaFruit Tool", "Gold Ingot Tool"}
for _, v in pairs(game.Workspace:GetChildren()) do
    for _, d in pairs(items) do
        if v.Name == d then
            wait(1)
            game.Players.LocalPlayer.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = v.CFrame
            print("tped")
        end
    end
end`

If you need any help, post questions in the comment section.

Ross.